# Gnome screenrulter has no color

Tags: gnome, colors

Since installing Ubuntu 22.04 (plus all updates) the gnome desktop screenruler has lost its color. I can restore it by clicking on its settings and choosing a color but it should automatically find a color from my color palette in my Ubuntu settings. I have reset the color palette and completely removed and reinstalled screenruler using the Synaptic package manager but nothing has worked. What's the cure please?

Comment: There must be an issue with that package. I can install it in a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, but it fails to open. Note that the help file dates from 2008, so possibly this software is not anymore maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue with the package. On a fresh Ubuntu installation, the application will even not load¹. The reason may be that the package is old and unmaintained. The  `man` page mentions a date of 2008.

Apart from debugging the source code, there is little that can be done. As an alternative, you may consider `kruler`, a similar application packaged as a snap application. You can install it using "Software".

---

Note

¹Starting `screenruler` at the terminal gives the following output:

```
$ screenruler 
Loading libraries...
Creating windows...
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb:89:in `sprintf': Infinity (FloatDomainError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb:89:in `bind_call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/delegate.rb:89:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/share/screenruler/preferences_window.rb:40:in `initialize'
    from ./screenruler.rb:77:in `new'
    from ./screenruler.rb:77:in `<main>'
```